# What is difference between findFragmentById() and creating an object of Fragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Here is an implementation of `findFragmentById()`

```
Custom_Fragment frag = findFragmentById(id);
```

Here is an implementation of creating a `Fragment` object

```
Custom_Fragment frag = new Custom_Fragment();
```

What is difference between `findFragmentById()` and creating an object of `Fragment` in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findFragmentById()` returns an existing instance (or `null`, if there is no instance found with the given ID).

By using the `new` keyword, a new instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

You should create fragment by static factory method and pass arguments in Bundle. As stated above, .findFragmentById(id) finds fragment, placed in layout container with given Id. there is another method .findFragmentByTag(String tag), where string is ay user- defined string. The latter is more handy.

Comment: By the way, "as stated above" means nothing. Answers have no guaranteed order